# How to pass view of different type to another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have this `TestView` which accepts `headerContent` and `bodyContent`,

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
  var headerContent: (() -> Content)?  = nil
  let bodyContent: () -> Content
  
  var body: some View {

    VStack {
      headerContent?()
      bodyContent()
    }
  }
}
```

And I use it as,

```
struct ContentView: View {  
  var body: some View {
    TestView(headerContent: {
      Text("HeaderContent")
    }) {
      ScrollView {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the following error,

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ScrollView<EmptyView>' to closure result type 'Text'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Change `var headerContent: (() -> Content)?` to `var headerContent:() -> some View)?`

Comment: @xTwisteDx I get `'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions`

Comment: It might be just `View` instead of `some View`, don't have my IDE in front of me atm.

Comment: Can you describe what you're attempting to do? The way you've got this setup doesn't make much sense and I'm almost certain it can be handled better.

Comment: @xTwisteDx Well I'm trying to pass two views to a struct - one will be shown at the top of the view and next just as a body. Also I get `Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` this error btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two `View` generics, since `headerContent` and `bodyContent` are not the same.

Without this, you are saying there is some concrete type `Content` that conforms to `View`. However, both `Text` and `ScrollView` are different types, not the same.

Code:

```
struct TestView<HeaderContent: View, BodyContent: View>: View {
    var headerContent: (() -> HeaderContent)? = nil
    let bodyContent: () -> BodyContent

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            headerContent?()
            bodyContent()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot @George

Comment: @swiftPunk You don't have to come after me lol. I didn't look at your answer. But yes your answer is the correct one.